# Downloading assets into unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cdn, 3d-modelling, assetbundle

I have 1000s of assets that needs to be downloaded in my unity game basis the request made by the user, what is the best approach to deal with this?

Comment: If all of them needed, download as a single zip.

Answer (score 2):

As evayly has already stated in another answer, the best way to go would be Asset Bundles.

Asset bundles can be any kind of Unity asset (like prefabs). They have to be built inside unity first though, before they can be accessed and downloaded into another Unity game.

I found the Unitys implementation of downloading assets a bit messy and awkward, so I am using an asset bundle manager from github (not the one from Unity) in my own project. 
https://github.com/SadPandaStudios/AssetBundleManager

It is fairly easy to use and gets the job done.

Comment: +1 For the AssetBundle Manager, I just found out that Unitys own ABM is not available on the Asset Store any longer, however, they are still refering to it on their docs. Maybe they just moved it around to some other place. The link in their docs is invalid...

Answer (score 1):

The "best way" to do this is to use AssetBundles.

I am using "best way" here as it is the way Unity devs would probably handle this.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

You can then download the AssetBundle by utilizing the UnityWebRequest API as stated here in the Workflow https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html .

Here is the Script reference.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html